# What's the standard way of including dependencies for your JavaScript tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and am wondering what's the standard/recommended way of including dependencies (e.g. Jasmine, jQuery) when writing tests for a JavaScript library? I'm using Jasmine as the test framework FWIW. Would it for instance be recommended to include libraries being depended on in the source tree?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you get started by simply including the dependencies in the HTML runner file via `<script>` tags. This isn't the only way, but it will get you started faster than any other method.

Also, since you are just starting, you might also want to consider trying Mocha. Here is an example mocha runner:

http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/example/tests.html

Comment: How would you include the dependencies physically though, e.g. in the source tree?

Comment: It actually depends on what you are testing. Are you testing something that is DOM related? If so, you want to setup an HTML test runner which allows you to add the script tags directly to the HTML page. Otherwise, you can simply use `require` statements in your test file to get a reference to the code under test. This assumes you are using Mocha since Mocha works in the browser and via NodeJs.